# cordova forked plugin not working android

Tags: android, cordova, github, plugins

I'm making a Cordova Android app. I have to make changes to the Cordova "Media" plugin, for better sound quality.

However In GitHub I fork the original Apache media Plugin [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ai45K.png). 
Then, without any modifications to the forked resp I  run :
 `'cordova plugin add https://github.com/mickedance/cordova-plugin-media.git'`

Then I run : 'cordova run android --device' There's no error, but the media-plugin isn't working. When I instead run
 `'cordova plugin adds cordova-plugin-media'` the plugin works fine.

What do I have to do more to make my forked resp work?

I have also tried to do download the resp, unzip it and run `'cordova C:\phonegap\cordova-plugin-media-master'` with same result.

I have tried to make changes to config file(s) but do not know exactly wich config file to change and what to change.

When forking another githubs users resp (mirko77/cordova-plugin-media) for the same plugin it works fine, I have tried to see differents in his code but haven't seen any different, so I guess there's something in some xml - file I have to make changes.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: I have made a workaround the main issue of recording in better soundquality, but the I can't figure out how to make the forked resp work. I even can't add a downloaded one and add it and making it work. So I'll keep this open. Hope that's ok since it's not solved.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you just installed the plugin but not applied into your javascript code.

Please refer the following,

[cordova-plugin-media](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media)

It gives you a explanation of how to install and how to use it.